# What statistical test is appropriate for correlations within repeated measures?

Tags: r, correlation, statistical-significance, repeated-measures

We have $N$ individuals measured repeatedly in time.

For each individual, at each measurement, we measure the values of two variables: $A$ and $B$.

The number of measurements per individual might not be the same.

The $i^{th}$ measurement of the $n^{th}$ individual might be taken at a different time than the $i^{th}$ measurement of the $m^{th}$ individual.

How can we compute the correlation between $A$ and $B$ and measure the significance of the correlation ?

What statistical test can we employ ?

Are there any package in `R` that does this ?

Comment: It's not quite clear to me what you're after. In what sense do you mean 'correlation' here?

Comment: Agreed with Glen_b. Your question is confusing. Saying what you did is good, but more importantly, tell us what you are trying to find. For example, are you interested in changes across time (across measurements within the individual)? Why did you take multiple measurements? How did you determine the timing of the measurements?